# Understanding alpha and beta factors in transistors

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I am a student and this is first time we are introduced to semiconductors. During studies I learned about the alpha and beta factor in a transistor. Actually I was doing some numericals were I got confused. There were two numerical problems

**Problem:1**  given data: current gain beta =(.97) common emitter configuration and collector current Ic =(2x10^-3)

**Problem:2**  given data: current gain alpha =(.96) common base configuration and collector current Ic =(60*10^-6)

The issue is the book says nothing about alpha factor and gives beta factor the name **current gain** but in numerical the alpha factor and beta factor both are called current gain. Is there something to do with the common base/common emitter configuration. Is there is some mistake in book numerical, if yes then what do we call alpha factor. Does alpha factor also have name like beta factor (current gain)

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the reason behind but yes it is due to the configuration. The common base has the current gain factor as alpha while the common emitter has the current gain factor as beta and common collector also has current gain denoted by gamma. So as in your problems the beta and alpha would be the current gain respectively.